# Computer-assisted translation for GWT recommendations

Tags: gwt, internationalization, translation

We are looking for a suitable solution to translate our GWT application collaboratively. We have a bunch of constants and messages property files that need to be translated by different people. Till now we've emailed the files and manually merged the translated content back which obviously doesn't scale very well.

Is there any tool (preferably an [open source project](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer-assisted_translation#Comparison_of_different_Translation_Memory_tools)) you can recommend that does play well with the i18n support of GWT and allow for collaboratively translation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look like there is a GWT optimized solution for supporting the translation process of `.properties` files.

We are currently evaluating [Pootle](http://translate.sourceforge.net/wiki/pootle/index). It is easy to use (especially for non-techies), supports the translation process in many ways, supports user management, is open source and lets you import and export property files easily (which is important for integrating with GWT).

Answer (score 0):

There is a [Google Language API for GWT](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-apis/wiki/LanguageGettingStarted)

Comment: We are not looking for a translation service (i.e., like http://translate.google.com/?hl=de&tab=wT#auto|en|) but for a tool that shows what properties need to be translated (by humans) to what language etc. An example can be found at http://pootle.locamotion.org/projects/firefox36/

Answer (score 0):

I hope this doesn't sound like spam, but we built [Amanuens](http://amanuens.com), which is a web-based tool designed exactly to solve the problems you're having.

I'm not into GWT, but I assume that you have .properties files. If so, then our solution should work fine (although it's not open source).

Comment: Thanks, but we are really looking for an open source solution.