# Tools for manual translation of Constants/Messages .properties files

Tags: gwt, translate

I'm looking for some tools that could be used by human translators during the process of translating our GWT application into other languages.

Currently, we have the English version of .properties files containing constants and messages, and need create the files for other languages. This tool should be easy to use, so even non-IT-lover can master it.

Or, do you suggest other method for translation of the texts?

- I heard the "community" approach becomes quite popular, by that I mean that one uploads his texts to some (?) forum, and the community there creates the translations into other language - but as I said, I don't know much about this
- Are there any online platforms for this purpose?
- any other ideas?

Comment: Looks like you're looking for a similar solution we did (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5883493/computer-assisted-translation-for-gwt-recommendations/6252027#6252027). Might be useful for you too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my SO answer for [VB 6 source code, speech text is in french want to translate to english](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6246522/vb-6-source-code-speech-text-is-in-french-want-to-translate-to-english/6247160#6247160).  The same answer works if you replace the computer langauge "VB6" by "JavaScript".